# I am confused about this contradiction in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames, time-dilation

Consider a stationary object and an object moving at half the speed of light to the right and light moving to the right past them. To observe light moving at the same speed that the stationary object sees the light moving at, it has to experience half the time that the stationary object experiences and that is because when the stationary object sees the light moving a certain distance the moving object will see the light have moved half the distance, so it must see the light moving half the distance in half the time for the speed of light to be the same. But if you consider another light moving in the opposite direction, for the moving object to see that light moving at the same speed that the stationary object sees that light moving at, it must experience double the time that the stationary object experiences because the moving object will see the light moving double the distance this time. The problem here is that the moving object can not experience both half the time, and double the time that the stationary object experiences, which means that the moving object cannot see both lights moving at the same speed (the speed of light). But special relativity states that light speed is constant for all frames of reference. So how can a moving object see all lights moving in different directions all moving at the same speed of light which the stationary object sees these lights moving at?

Comment: Please provide answers with examples. I don't want someone to say length contraction will solve the problem, or whatever concept you didn't consider will solve the problem. I can answer any question this way, I can say "oh you haven't considered this, your problem is solved." That is not how to solve problems if you think a concept can solve a problem, show how it will provide an example or explanation of how it will solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can try to provide a diagram and animation if that would help. If I could rephrase it, is what you're saying is that $t=0$, in the stationary object's frame, there's a left-mover and a right-mover emitting flashes of light, and you don't understand how everyone can agree the flashes of light are moving at the speed of light?

Comment: @David no there is light being emitted from the stationary observer to the left and to the right. And there is only a right mover. How does the right mover see both lights moving at the speed of light if you can't have two different amounts of time passing for the right mover when a specific amount of time passes for the stationary observer?

Comment: @David I just need to understand how much time passes for the right mover when 1 second passes for the stationary observer. And now if that amount of time passes for the right mover when 1 second passes for the stationary then how does the mover see the same speed of light in both directions, when you know that the light to the left is going to be further away from the right mover than the light on the right meaning that in the amount of time that passed for the right mover the two lights moved different distances from the right mover's perspective, so the speeds of the lights are different.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the relativity of simultaneity. The Lorentz transform is more than just time dilation and length contraction. The relativity of simultaneity is also essential.

Not only is the time dilated and length contracted, but also the moving clocks are de synchronized so that leading clocks lag. This allows for the speed of light to be c in all directions in both frames.

The easiest way to demonstrate this is as follows:

The equation of a sphere expanding from the origin in all directions at the speed of light is $$ x'^2 + y'^2 + z'^2 = c^2 t'^2$$ This is a pulse of light at the origin travelling in all directions outward at c.

We use the Lorentz transform, which includes time dilation, length contraction, and the relativity of simultaneity, to transform this into the unprimed frame and obtain $$(x-tv)^2\gamma^2+y^2+z^2=\left( c t \gamma-\frac{v x \gamma}{c}\right)^2$$ which simplifies to $$x^2+y^2+z^2=c^2 t^2$$ thus showing that the speed of light is the same in both frames in all directions, not just in one specific direction.

Comment: If I understand simultaneity correctly, it means that if two events happen simultaneously in one reference frame they don't necessarily happen simultaneously in the other reference frames. But here only one event is happening and both observers are observing the duration of that event. Light is moving a certain distance and both observers are measuring how much time has passed. Simultaneity should have no effect here. If it does please show how it would solve the problem by giving an example. length contraction maybe could provide a solution to my problem, but I fail to understand how.

Comment: No, there are at least six events of interest here. Two emissions of light (one on one side and one on the other), then the two events where the stationary observer receives each flash and the two events where the moving observer receives each flash

Comment: Re, "...observing the duration of that event..." _Events_ don't have duration. What you're describing—I'm not sure what to call it, maybe an "interval"—has a _beginning_ and an _end._ Those are two distinct events.

Comment: How does the concept of simultaneity help solve the problem presented above? I want an example of how this contradiction be avoided by the concept of simultaneity. I can only see this solving a problem if I assumed that two events were simultaneous in my situation and they are not simultaneous because of the relativity of simultaneity. But in the situation I haven't based the contradiction on any events needing to be simultaneous.

Comment: Simultaneity is inherently a part of any measure of the distance between relatively moving objects. This is because the distance is the difference in positions at the same time. but i will give a simple derivation in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Understanding simultaneity is the most important aspect of learning SR, as you will find that both length contraction and time dilation are the consequence of the lack of simultaneity.

The relativity of simultaneity means that a plane of fixed time in one frame of reference is a sloping slice through time in a frame that is moving relative to the first frame.

To take your specific example, if light leaves the stationary object at time t=0, and moves off to the left and right, after a second in the frame of the stationary object the light will be about 300,000km away in each direction. So let's suppose there happen to be clocks 300,000km away in both directions, they will each read t=1s as the light passes them.

Now from the perspective of the person moving to the right at 0.5c, when the light is passing the right hand clock, it has only travelled about 150,000km ahead of that person. Conversely, however, the light that is passing the left hand clock is about 450,000km away. How can that be resolved if the speed of light is the same in each direction from the perspective of the moving person?

Firstly, you will see straight away that the concept of time dilation cannot explain it, as around half a second appears to have passed in the forward direction (ie to the right) and about one and a half seconds seem to have passed in the opposite direction to the left.

The answer is that the moving and stationary observers disagree about what time it is at the left and right hand clocks when the light passes them. The stationary observer thinks t=1s at each of the clocks. The travelling observer thinks t=0.5 by the right hand clock, so the clock is running 0.5 seconds ahead, while the time by the left hand clock is t=1.5, so the left hand clock is lagging by 0.5s.

So to the travelling observer the stationary clocks are out of synch. It is *not* a matter of time dilation, but of the fact that the two events (of the light passing the left and right hand clocks) are simultaneous in the frame of the stationary observer but happen at different times in the frame of the travelling observer.

Comment: The problem is not that the stationary clocks are out of synch to the moving observer it is understandable. But the problem is that if you have two moving clocks moving at 0.5c to the right with the moving observer and they start in the same positions as the stationary clocks. Now as light moves to the right it would take 2 seconds to reach the moving clock to the right.  And the light traveling to the left would take 0.5 seconds to reach the moving left clock. Now the problem is that the moving observer can not see the moving clocks to be out of sync since they are in the same reference frame

Comment: Now if you say that time is going to dilate so that the moving observer will see 1 second when the light reaches the right clock (so that it can see the same speed of light as the stationary observer) then the same dilation will not work on the left clock since the observer will now only see 0.25s passing in the left clock meaning that the observer will see the light to the left traveling at 4 times the speed of light since it passed the same distance in a quarter of the time.

Comment: No, you are missing the point, and you are confusing yourself by thinking the effect is caused by time dilation. It is nothing to do with time dilation. It is caused by the fact that local time in one frame is systematically out of synch with local time in the other.

Comment: Length contraction doesn't solve the problem since the distance needs to be contracted in one direction and expanded in the other direction for the speed of light to be the same in all directions. The length to the left moving clock needs to expand and the length to the right moving clock needs to contract. The problem here is that the formula for length contraction contracts length the same way in all directions. There is no different values for different directions.

Comment: In the frame of the moving clocks, the time will be 1s when and where light has moved one light second from its source. Likewise in the frame of the stationary clocks. The point is that a time of 1s at a given place in one frame will be a different local time in the other.

Comment: Forget length contraction too!!!! Neither length contraction nor time dilation account for the effect- it is all down to the fact that when it is a constant time, say t=1s everywhere in one frame it is not a constant time anywhere in the other frame, and vice versa.

Comment: You should be able to figure it out from my answer. If you and I stand together and we flash a beam of light to the left and right, after a second the light is 300,000km away from us in each direction...

Comment: ...but if you walk after the beam to the right at 1m/s, then when it is 300,000km to the right of me it is 1m less far away from you, and conversely when it is 300,000km to the left of me it is 1m more than 300,000km away from you. So to you, light has travelled different distances to the left and right at the moments when it has travelled the same distances to the left and right in my frame. Now, figure out what that means

Comment: I think I kinda understand what your answer is. It is that the clocks are lagging some time or ahead some time from the beginning. So there is a 0.5-second lag in the clock to the left and the clock to the right is ahead by 0.5 seconds. But if that is true the lag 0.5 seconds should stay and should not increase as the moving object moves. Because the moving object will keep watching the clock ensuring it doesn't lag. So unless there is dilation in time the lag should stay constant. But now if the moving object continues moving for 1 second more from the stationary point of view light will...

Comment: light will be 300,000 km away to the right and 900,000 km away to the left. So The moving object should see a lag of 1 second on the right clock this time and the left clock to be ahead by 1 second. But how did the lag increase as the object continued moving? This means it must not be just a lag. It must be either time dilation or length contraction. And we already know time dilation and length contraction don't solve the problem.

Comment: Because it is a lead/lag that is proportional to distance. The further away from you, the greater the lead/lag is. It is exactly the same as a flat piece of ground next to a ramp- the further you move along the ramp in either direction, the higher or lower it becomes relative to level ground. So it is with tilted planes of simultaneity- the differences in time increase with distance in each direction.

Comment: The good news is that I think you are getting close to working it all out. So the lead/lag of 0.5 seconds when the light is 300,000km away in my frame becomes a 1s lead lag when the light is 600,000km away, and a 1.5s lead/lag 900,000km away and so on. Once you have that worked out and you are comfortable with it, let me know, and I will explain how it causes time dilation.

Comment: A lag in time means that the clock was originally ahead by some time but the amount of time the clock was originally ahead by cannot increase. That is nonsense. You cannot change the past and change how much time the clock was originally ahead by. If you mean that the amount of time passing for the moving object is slower or faster to explain why the difference between the stationary and moving times keeps increasing then that is in fact time dilation. But time cannot be both moving faster and slower for the moving object. When 1 second passes for the still object, it can't be that both 0.5..

Comment: it can't be that both 0.5, and 1.5 seconds passed for the moving object. only a specific amount of time must have passed for the moving object.

Comment: You are completely wrong. In the frame of the stationary object the light is 300,000km to the right after 1s. That corresponds to a time of 0.5s in the frame of the moving object. At the same time, 1s, in the frame of the stationary object, light is also 300,000km to the left. But that is not 'at the same time' in the frame of the moving object- in that frame the time is later, 1.5s.

Answer (score 0):

This spacetime diagram may help.
The diamonds represent the light signals in a light-clock.
The resulting diamonds give us a graphically accurate visualization of
the ticks of time and space according an observer.
The rotated graph paper helps us draw these diamonds for different observers.

I use $V=(3/5)$ to make the arithmetic easier.

[image: robphy-RRGP-speedOfLight]

A light-flash at event O travels in all directions.

The observer at rest in this diagram measures the velocity of the forward light-signal as
$$\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{(+5)}{(5)}=1,$$
because after 5 of her ticks, that light signal is 5 of her space-ticks ("sticks") in the forward direction.

The moving observer in this diagram has velocity
$$V=\frac{(+3)}{(5)}.$$

The moving observer in this diagram measures the velocity of the forward light-signal as
$$\frac{\Delta x'}{\Delta t'}=\frac{(+5)}{(5)}=1,$$
because after 5 of his ticks, that light signal is 5 of his space-ticks ("sticks") in the forward direction.

Similarly for the backward light-signal, both measure a velocity of $-1$.

Both of these observers measure the same value of the speed (magnitude of the velocity) of a light-signal.